# Can't edit file on android (wpa_supplicant is read only)

Tags: android

So i'm trying to connect 3 cameras (andoer 360) to one access point on my mobile.
I want to edit the wpa_supplicant_ap.conf, but this file is read only and i can't change it.

I'd really appreciate some help cause i can't move on.

Answer (score 0):

`wpa_supplicant.conf` file description from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8/+/master/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf) says that

```
# NOTE! This file may contain password information and should probably be made 
# readable only by root user on multiuser systems.
```

Typical file directory is `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`

You need root access to edit it or change access rights. Without root access only the mechanism of flashing an update (via recovery or OTA) can modify `/system`. There might be a way via a custom recovery which lets you edit all file systems directly (for example [TWRP](https://twrp.me/)).

[Here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=855631) and [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/30236/wpa-supplicant-conf-for-android-hotspot) is the same problem.